# Can my mother board use this card?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, agp

Can this old mother board: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c00041640 use this card : [http://www.amazon.com/HIS-Radeon-Native-Graphics-H467QS1GHA/dp/B003CYKCG8/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003CYKCG8) ?

Comment: What is the CPU being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of things, yes.

from the mobo specs

```
AGP Graphics Support    Yes
AGP Graphics Maximum Mode   AGP 8X
Graphics Connector  AGP 8x
```

AGP 8x is the most recent/last revision of AGP, and considering yours is a a modern card, it should work.

Comment: I would also check to make sure you have a 400 Watt power supply. The HIS Website states that as a requirement.  http://www.hisdigital.com/un/product2-535.shtml

Answer (score 0):

*Despite this does not directly answers your question, you might find useful to be aware of this before making any decisions...*

You have some considerations to attend to before rushing to buy/use that HIS HD 4670 card on your motherboard:

1. **Dimension**

   The graphics card is 20cm long, so make sure it fits.
2. **Memory**

   The HIS HD 4670 used DDR3 SDRAM, that is neither forward nor backward compatible with any earlier type of random access memory (RAM) due to different signaling voltages, timings, and other factors.

   Your motherboard uses Socket 478 CPUs, meaning DDR SDRAMM memory modules. There's a big difference in operating specs between both of them.
3. **Power**

   A PSU for your motherboard doesn't need to be as demanding as one for the HIS HD 4670 card, that will draw most of its power from the +12v line and if the PSU is old it may not have enough output to drive that faster card.

This are some primary considerations to take into consideration. More details can be analyzed if a more comprehensive knowledge of your remaining hardware gets provided.

Comment: The ram on the system should have no effect on the video card ram type - with video cards DDR3 is the 'cheaper' alternative to GDDR4/5 (i forget which is the current one) and is used on cheaper cards. Most cards in modern systems as such would be using a different type of ram from the system they are on - i'm currently using a video card with DDR3 on a system that uses DDR2 ram

Comment: Yes, should have no effect, but the FSB needs to be adjusted! Nonetheless, I'm just pointing out potential issues based on the little information provided. :)